# Error code 1215: Why Can't I Add Foreign Key

Tags: python, mysql

I cannot figure out why I can't add foreign key to my table... Can someone help me out? This is what I'm having trouble with:

```
CREATE TABLE Albums(
album_id INTEGER,
producer_id CHAR(6)NOT NULL,
release_date DATE,
album_title VARCHAR(30)NOT NULL,
price NUMERIC(5,2),
PRIMARY KEY(album_id),
FOREIGN KEY(producer_id)REFERENCES Musicians(sin));
```

The above code works

```
CREATE TABLE Orders(
order_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
album_id INTEGER,
album_title VARCHAR(30)NOT NULL,
price NUMERIC(5,2),
PRIMARY KEY(order_id, album_id),
FOREIGN KEY (album_id) REFERENCES Albums(album_id),
FOREIGN KEY (album_title) REFERENCES Albums(album_title),
FOREIGN KEY (price) REFERENCES Albums(price));
```

But this doesn't. I don't know why but I can't add album_title and price as Foreign Keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what the documentation says:

> A FOREIGN KEY constraint does not have to be linked only to a PRIMARY
>   KEY constraint in another table; it can also be defined to reference
>   the columns of a UNIQUE constraint in another table.

So `album_title` and `price` should be either PRIMARY KEY or should have UNIQUE Constraint in the `Albums` Table.